# n-dimensional TicTacToe diagonal checker (predicting who will win with one just one move)

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm given a state of a Tic-Tac-Toe game. It is a n*n game and the winner is the person who can have "a" number of consecutive X or Os (which a is also given). I should predict weather X or O can win in next state of the game. for example if the state is like this:

```
X X O X O
X O X O X
O X O - -
- - - - -
X O X O X
```

the output is:

```
O
```

I have problem with the diagonal checking. I wrote a code.

```
X = 'X'
O = 'O'
DASH = '-'

def o_left_diagonal_checker_winner(game_board, n, a):
    x_counter = 0
    for j in range(n):
        for i in range(1, n):
            if i - 1 >= 0 and n - i >= 0:
                if game_board[i - 1][n - i] == X:
                    x_counter += 1
                if n - i - 2 >= 0 and i - 2 >= 0 and x_counter == a - 1 and game_board[n - i - 2][i - 2] == DASH:
                    return O
                else:
                    x_counter = 0
```

this part of code will check the game from left top to right. but it doesn't work. If you have better algorithm please tell me and I can't use libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this alternative solution.

Given that you have an array representing your game board. With values +1,-1,0 for the different states of each position. Then take a d*d size sub array and do a sum along the diagonals. rows and columns. If any value = -2 or 2 then the player +1 or -1 has a chance to win in the next state. d would be the size of your array. Here is an example for a 5*5 board with win condition of 3. So simply masking the board with the win possibilities will predict the next winner.

```
import numpy as np
board = np.array([[-1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.],
                  [-1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                  [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
                  [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                  [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

win_length = 3


#lets assume +1 = X, -1 = 0 and 0 = nothing
# Also assume that X always starts
# You could also simply replace priority with who is moving next
def who_wins_next(board,a):
    priority = sum(sum(board))

    if priority >0: # If else case to automatically determine who is moving next. Alternatively you can add another input to who is moving next to replace this
        target = 2
        text = "X (1)"
    else:
        target = -2
        text = "O (-1)"


    width,height = board.shape
    for i in range(width-a+1):
        for j in range(height-a+1):
            sub = board[i:i+a,j:j+a]
            diagonal_forward = sum(sub[i][i] for i in range(a))
            diagonal_backward = sum(sub[i][a-i-1] for i in range(a))
            row_sums = np.sum(sub,axis=1) #Using numpy sum with axis to get an array of row sums
            col_sums = np.sum(sub,axis=0) # Likewise for columns
            if diagonal_forward == target or diagonal_backward == target or target in list(row_sums) or target in list(col_sums):
                #Only need to know if win is possible. Not how.
                return text + " can win in next step"
    return text + " cannot win in next step"
```

Comment: and what about checking if there is a empty place that players can play

Comment: The code inherently checks if one can win in the next step. If there are no more moves it will simply show that it cannot be won. Otherwise simply check that there are no zeros in the board array.

Comment: Can we write it without using numpy library?

Comment: I guess you could using nested lists or python arrays. But its much easier with numpy.